# Execute call after another is completed on .onAppear{} swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift3, realm

I have a condition inside the onAppear on my swiftui View

I want to execute the if condition **after** my firstCall() ends

My onAppear:

```
 .onAppear{
        
        firstCall()
        
        
        if mybool{ // I want this to be executed just after the firstCall() is completed
            value = repo.secondCall(int: self.initialValue)
        }
        
    }
```

The firstCall method that I want to end before the if condition to be executed

```
func firstCall(){
        
         Task{
            do{
                try await repo.firstCall().watch(block: {myView in
                    
                    self.initialValue = myView
                    
                    
                })
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
```

I need this because I need to have a value for my **self.initialValue** before executing the if statement.

Also, the second call will be executed rarely, so what is the best performance way of doing this on swiftui, I am new to swift.

My repo.firstCall()

```
fun firstCall(): CommonFlow<User?> {
        return realm.query<User>("_id = $0", ObjectId.from(userId)).asFlow().map {
            it.list.firstOrNull()
        }.asCommonFlow()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change first call to a proper async await format

```
func firstCall() async {
        do{
            try await repo.firstCall().watch(block: {myView in
                
                self.initialValue = myView
                
                
            })
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    
}
```

Then use `.task`

```
.onAppear{
    Task{
    await firstCall()
    
    if mybool{ // I want this to be executed just after the firstCall() is completed
        value = repo.secondCall(int: self.initialValue)
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use for iOS 14 as well, task only available for iOS 15 :(

Comment: @dhaval123 you can use Task inside onAppear too but know that it is a weakness.

Comment: I tried, it does not work, call are executed at the same time

Comment: @dhaval123 not if you wrap them both, see above. The only reason this wouldn’t work is if first call isn’t proper asynchrony await function

Comment: try `await firstCall()`

Comment: Still not, I tried adding the Task on the onAppear

Comment: neither work with the await firstCall()

Comment: the if statement its still executed first..

Comment: @dhaval123 then the issue is your repo.firstCall( it isn’t a proper async await function

Comment: I ve added my repo.firstCall() on top, its a kotlin function

Comment: It is a simple db get.. it shouldve work, do you know any alternatives?

Comment: My Kotlin skills are very raw but I believe my suspicions to be true you need a `suspend` function or convert with `continuation` https://johnoreilly.dev/posts/swift_async_await_kotlin_coroutines/ that `block` part isn't `async await`

Comment: I appreciat for the help anyway